# Which series it would be?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I had an exam of Mathematics in which I was asked a question of identifying a series, and then taking a sum of it.

Series was

```
1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + ... + 99^3 + 100^3
```

My guess was that it is Arithmetic series, but my friend told me I had to first solve the power and then check for the series which would make it to be

```
1 + 8 + 27 + ... so on
```

I think it would be Arithmetic series without solving the power and just handling it out, am I right? Or was he right in first solving the power and then finding the type of the series it makes?

The total number of Series that are in my mind

1. Arithmetic Series
2. Geometric series
3. Harmonic Series
4. Miscellaneous series

According to me, it would go to the Arithmetic.

Comment: Does it have a constant difference? $8-1=7, 27-8=19$ so it is not an arithmetic series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an arithmetic series.  For an arthimetic series, the difference between successive terms is constant.  But $8-1 \neq 27-8$.  It is also not a geometric series, for which the ratio of successive terms is constant.  $\frac 81 \neq \frac {27}8$.  What other choices have you got?

Comment: Yes, that was the thing I came up with the question, I have added the 4 types of series I read in my book. I matches none of them!

Comment: So look up the definition of harmonic series and see if it fits the same way I checked the other two.  Miscellaneous is none of the above, so if it is not harmonic it is miscellaneous.

Comment: Yeah maybe! Harmonic is the Reciprocal of the Arithmetic series :) 1/a + 1/a+d etc..:)

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the following formulas?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\quad
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
There is a similar formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n i^3$

Comment: So, what series would that be? I did read the formula, but it slipped from my mind! :( Can you tell me please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples

Answer (score 0):

It is just a power sum, or simply the sum of cubic powers. 
The closed formula is $S_n = \frac{(n+1)^2n^2}{2^2}$ aka Faulhabers Formula. You can derive such sums by a polynomial approach. E.g. $S_n=1^2+2^2+3^2+...n^2$ has to be a polynomial of 3 degree in n. So $S_n = a_0+a_1*n+a_2*n^2+a_3*n^3$, plug in some vaules for the sum and then solve for the coefficients.